# BMI Calculator with name, weight, height, BMI and text using Array and for cycle

Tags: java, arrays, variables, calculator

I would like to ask how do I do that when the cycle starts and go over again, the string variable name will increase by 1. This program is supposed to ask you how many patients are you going to write. If you write for ex. 10, then the cycle will go for 10 times and it will ask all those information I want and then add them to the array which I have already created called BMI. This whole program is supposed to print you a table which contains Name, Height in meters, weight in Kg, your calculated BMI and then text in what state of BMI are you ATM. The problem is how do I do it? I just started learning arrays and stuff like that and my teacher gave me this homework. I don't think that this homework is hard but just hard to understand what to do.

Things I already tried is creating a for cycle with String called name something like this: String name(); but that obviously did not work.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Pacient {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int pole;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String pacient; 

        System.out.print("Zadej kolik bude pacientu: "); //How many patients do you want? For ex. 10

        pacient = input.nextLine();
        input.nextLine();
        pole = Integer.parseInt(pacient);

        String[][] bmi = new String[4][pole]; //This is supposed to make an array with my patients.

        double vaha; //weight
        double vyska; //height
        String jmeno; //name
        double telo1, telo2; //body for calc.
        String vysledek; //result
        int i,x=0,j, pa=0, k=0; //some variables

        bmi[0][0] = "Jmeno"; //First line of final table NAME
        bmi[0][1] = "Vaha"; // WEIGHT
        bmi[0][2] = "Vyska"; //HEIGHT
        bmi[0][3] = "BMI"; //BMI based on calc.
        bmi[0][4] = "Text"; //Final result

        for(int y=1;y<pole;y++){
            pa++;
            x++;

            System.out.print("Zadej svoje krestni jmeno: ");
            jmeno = input.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Zadej svoji vahu v Kg: ");
            vaha = input.nextDouble();

            System.out.print("Zadej svoji vysku v m: ");
            vyska = input.nextDouble();

            System.out.println("Vase informace byly uspesne ulozeny! ");


            bmi[1][0] = jmeno; //These values should somehow increase but idk 
                                 how atm and be assign with the patient which 
                                 will be printed at the end.
            bmi[1][1] = vaha2;
            bmi[1][2] = vyska2;
            bmi[1][3] = telo3;
            bmi[1][4] = vysledek;

        }

        // System.out.println("Tisknu tabulku");

        // telo1 = vyska * vyska; //Some calc. of BMI
        // telo2 = vaha / telo1;


        // if (telo2 < 18.5) { //Adding text to the result variable
        //     vysledek = "mate podvahu";
        // } else if (telo2 < 25) {
        //     vysledek = "Jste v normach";
        // } else if (telo2 < 30) {
        //     vysledek = "Nadvaha";
        // } else {
        //     vysledek = "Obezita";
        // }

        // String telo3 = String.valueOf(telo2); //Converting to strings
        // String vyska2 = String.valueOf(vyska);
        // String vaha2 = String.valueOf(vaha);

        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------");

        for(i=0;i<pole;i++) {
            for(j = 0; j<5; j++) System.out.print(bmi[i][j] + " ");
                System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------");
    }
}
```

Atm the program is just printing most of the time NULL NULL NULL NULL, and it does not match with the patient number. How do add all this code to for cycle and make it automatic convert int and double to strings and then print them correctly and assign them to the BMI Array. If you have any further questing, feel free to ask.

Comment: `bmi[1][0] = jmeno;` Use `y` for the first index, i.e. `bmi[y][0] = jmeno;`, rather than hard-coding 1.

Comment: You also probably want to use a better structure for patient data, e.g. a class rather than an array of five strings, but I guess you haven't learned about that yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have corrected the issues in code. Everything is explained step-by-step in comments. I have converted variable name in English for my understanding. If you have questions. Please ask.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Pacient {
    private static Scanner input;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int numberOfPatients; // Variables that saves number of patient
        // Asking user the number of patients
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many patients do you want?: ");
        // I have change this to nextInt
        // From javadoc "Scans the next token of the input as an int"
        // It is essentially next() + parseInt()
        numberOfPatients = input.nextInt();
        // nextInt() does not move cursor to next line
        // using nextLine() here would move it to next line and close
        // previous line otherwise it creates issue when you will use next/nextLine again
        input.nextLine();

        // String[][] array = new String[Rows][Columns];
        // For each patient there is a row. Since in the code there is header
        // as well that's why we need numberOfPatients + 1
        String[][] bmi = new String[numberOfPatients + 1][5]; 

        // All corresponding columns  
        bmi[0][0] = "Name"; // First line of final table NAME
        bmi[0][1] = "Weight"; // WEIGHT
        bmi[0][2] = "Height"; // HEIGHT
        bmi[0][3] = "BMI"; // BMI based on calc.
        bmi[0][4] = "Result"; // Final result

        // Starting from 1. Skipping header 
        for (int y = 1; y <= numberOfPatients; y++) {
            // Using y instead of an int. This way the loop will
            // automatically move to next row

            // Instead of saving it to variable and then to array 
            // I am saving it directly
            System.out.print("Enter your first name: ");
            bmi[y][0] = input.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Enter your weight in Kg: ");
            bmi[y][1] = input.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Enter your height in m: ");
            bmi[y][2] = input.nextLine();

            // Using the information from above to calculate BMI
            // Basically I am storing and calculating at the same time
            // parseDouble converts String into double 
            // Math.pow(a,b) is powber function. a is base and b is exponent 
            double weight = Double.parseDouble(bmi[y][1]);
            double heightSquare = Math.pow(Double.parseDouble(bmi[y][2]), 2);
            double bmiCalculated = weight / heightSquare;

            // Based on BMI assigning result in result column
            bmi[y][3] = bmiCalculated + "";
            if (bmiCalculated < 18.5) {
                bmi[y][4] = "You are underweight";
            } else if (bmiCalculated > 18.5 && bmiCalculated < 25) {
                bmi[y][4] = "You are normal";
            } else if (bmiCalculated > 25 && bmiCalculated < 30) {
                bmi[y][4] = "You are overweight";
            } else {
                bmi[y][4] = "You are obese";
            }
            System.out.println("Your information has been saved successfully!");
        }

        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------");

        // In java 2D arrays are multiple 1D array stacked on each other
        // bmi.length gives the number of rows
        // Basically you iterate through each row and print each individual row
        // like 1D array
        for (int i = 0; i < bmi.length; i++) {
        // bmi[i] gives ith row. Which is 1D array. So you can print it like normal array
            for (int j = 0; j < bmi[i].length; j++)
                System.out.print(bmi[i][j] + " ");
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration of array and implementation is conflicting. You've fixed the first dimension and kept the second, variable. But you're using as if the first one is variable and second is fixed.

You should declare your array like

`String[][] bmi = new String[pole+1][4];`

`pole+1` because you're using first row for table headings

Your first loop should look like this

```
for(int y = 1; y < pole+1; y++){
    for(int z = 0; z < 4; z++){
        String data="ask user for data";
        bmi[y][z] = data; //similar for all
    }
}
```

Your output `for` loop will also look like above.